# Why does AJAX (reload div every x time) not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to reload a div every x time. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-6" id="myDesign" id="show">

          <h3>Show my cars:</h3>

          <?php $controller->getEvents(); ?>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
* ...In a document ready function... *

setInterval(function () {
        $('#show').reload()
    }, 3000);
```

I think my reload function ist not correct at the "$('#show').reload()" line.

Comment: What is `reload` even supposed to _be_ here? jQuery does not have a method of that name, to my knowledge. _“I think my reload function ist not correct”_ - and I think, you just completely _made it up_ to begin with. Go read https://api.jquery.com/load/, that is the usual way to do a thing like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the load function:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $('#show').load('/path/to/server/source');
}, 2000) /* time in milliseconds (ie 2 seconds)*/
```